# Como reiniciar servidor NodeJS

Tags: nodejs

Tengo claro que nodemon y otros módulos me sirven, para reiniciar el servidor cuando realizo cambios en los archivos , pero no es lo que deseo, pregunto, como podría reiniciar el servidor node en el momento que desee?, ejemplo:

```
app.post('/rein',(req, res, next) => {

//codigo para mandar a reinicar luego de la peticion

})
```

Comment: Podrías usar algo como `fs.writeFile` dentro de esa ruta para modificar el contenido de un archivo `dummy.js` que gatillara el reinicio de `nodemon`. O podrías usar `nodemon` [como módulo](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/requireable.md) y hacer `nodemon.emit('restart');` dentro de esa ruta

Comment: ya solucione el problema, cluesterise la aplicacion , y cada vez que necesito reiniciar , igual le emito a los cluster un restart y se reinicia el server , pero gracias igual , probare con el **nodemon.emit('restart')**

Comment: Con qué clusterizaste? PM2 ?

Comment: con el mismo modulo cluster de node

Comment: que ademas ayuda para dar mejor respuesta de peticiones

Comment: Por el balanceo de carga dices tú? Prueba PM2, te va a cambiar la vida

Comment: @Travv deberías poner eso como respuesta en lugar de como comentario en la pregunta. En Stack Overflow en español se promueve que los usuarios respondan a sus propias preguntas si encuentran las respuestas.

Comment: el problema de esa solución es que me resolvió el problema de momento pero trajo otras consecuencias , y no fue una solución factible , por eso es que no lo puse como respuesta

Comment: @Travv ¿encontraste una solución posterior que funcionara? ¿O sigues con el problema?

Comment: Por otros factores, tuve que cambiar parte de la implementación del proyecto y ya no necesite reiniciarlo.